# TWINT show Iâ€™m instead of I'm

Tags: python, character-encoding, tweets

I am scraping tweeter using twint. But all the `'` symbol will show as `â€™`
For example `I'm` = `Iâ€™m`  `Haven't` = `Havenâ€™t`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use `str.replace('â€™', '\'')`

Comment: You're decoding UTF-8 encoded bytes as cp1252 (or some other 8 bit encoding).